# Syntax error when assigning a variable Python

Tags: python

I keep getting a syntax error in this code on answer += rom_val[s[x]] - rom_val[s[x - 1]]:

```
def roman_to_decimal(s):
        answer = 0
        rom_val = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
        for x in range(len(s)):
                if rom_val[s[x]] > rom_val[[s[x - 1]]:
                        answer += rom_val[s[x]] - rom_val[s[x - 1]]
                else:
                        answer += rom_val[s[x]]
        return answer

print(roman_to_decimal('IV'))
```

I get the error when assigning the variable answer. I don't see a problem in that

Comment: Can you show us the full traceback?

Comment: `[[s[x - 1]]` has a missing close bracket, (or too many opens).

Comment: @Brian Yeah, I realized after I posted the comment

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `[`:

```
if rom_val[s[x]] > rom_val[[s[x - 1]]:
#                          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `rom_val[s[x]] > rom_val[[s[x - 1]]`, count the number of opening and closing brackets. You will see there is an extra opening bracket in `rom_val[[s`.

---

Note: These errors are easy to spot if your IDE/text editor code formatting. Because of the missing closing bracket the next line would be formatted with the wrong indentation and you would easily notice that something was off.

Comment: It does not appear that the OP is missing a closing bracket, but rather that they have an extra opening bracket.

Comment: That is true. I would't try to guess if we dind't know what `rom_val` is, but since we know it is a dictionary then you are right, there is an extra opening bracket instead of a missing closing bracket.